# Is it possible to register default Subscriber for some publisher

Tags: project-reactor

I have few questions:

1) Every time I create a Flux/Mono, I have to provide subscriber object. My understanding is that, we should register subscriber object somewhere one time(or you can say, mark default subscriber among many). Do we have some way to do that.

2) My build will run indefinitely, so should I create only one subscriber object or new every time i create a flux/mono. Currently I am working with spring 4 and I have created multiple subscriber beans. Since spring beans are by default singleton, I am using same subscriber object. Is that okay?

In Short, I want to create a flux of different events, and then just call some **no** **subscriber argument method**, and subscribers which have previously registered at some place earlier, should handle them automatically. Currently i have to handle them separately which seems duplicated effort.